# How to get an ordered count of month names from a datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe called WorkOrders that looks like this

[image]

what I want to do is to convert the format of the timestamp in the index so the index reads as 2018-Feb-27 10:47:00.

Then I can call a method to count the number of rows each month has. The following method using a lambda expression and group by returns

[image]

This is essentially what I am trying to do except the 1 becomes Jan, 2 becomes Feb ect. Using the `.month_name()` method works, but it is no longer in chronological order e.g.

[image]

This is what I would like to see except in the order of January, February, March ....

Answer (score 1):

- The desired format, `'2018-Feb-27 10:47:00'`, is a `str` not a `datetime64[ns] dtype`, which means `df.index.month` and `df[col].dt.month` can't be used to extract the month, because those methods don't work on `strings`.

### Option 1:

- I think it's easier to use the `calendar` module (part of the standard library) to get a `list` of month names, and then map the month number to the month name.

```py
import pandas as pd
from calendar

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(3000))}, index=pd.bdate_range('2021-01-21', freq='D', periods=3000))
df.index.name = 'Call Out Time'

# display(df.head())
               a
Call Out Time   
2021-01-21     3
2021-01-22     8
2021-01-23     7
2021-01-24     2
2021-01-25     9

# groupby month: the index must be a datetime dtype
dfg = df.groupby(df.index.month).size().reset_index(name='counts')

# map the month number to the month name
dfg['Call Out Time'] = dfg['Call Out Time'].map(dict(zip(range(1, 13), calendar.month_name[1:])))
```

### Option 2:

- With your existing implementation, use [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html), with `ordered=True`.

```py
# groupby month_name
dfg = df.groupby(df.index.month_name()).size().reset_index(name='counts')

# set as categorical
dfg['Call Out Time'] = pd.Categorical(dfg['Call Out Time'], categories=calendar.month_name[1:], ordered=True)

# sort the values
dfg = dfg.sort_values('Call Out Time').reset_index(drop=True)
```

### Result of both options:

```
   Call Out Time  counts
0        January     259
1       February     254
2          March     279
3          April     248
4            May     248
5           June     240
6           July     248
7         August     248
8      September     240
9        October     248
10      November     240
11      December     248
```